# How to properly set up SSL proxy in Apache?

Tags: ssl, proxy, apache-2.4

I'm trying to set up an SSL proxy to access a local web-app externally. I get a 500 error when accessing the page. The log says:

`[proxy:error] [pid 17153] (502)Unknown error 502: [client 192.168.1.109:56171] AH01084: pass request body failed to [::1]:5000 (localhost)`

In `httpd.conf` running on Apache 2.4.6, I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName web.domain.tld
    Redirect permanent / https://web.domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  web.domain.tld

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/chain.pem
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
    SSLProtocol  -All +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [7-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

    ProxyPass / https://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:5000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: localhost seems to resolve to ::1 (IPV6), are you sure there is something listening on it? what is the output of `netstat -an |grep LISTE` ?

Comment: The error is the same when I specify a local IP instead of `localhost`. I know the port is good because if I change `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `<VirtualHost *:5000>` along with related settings, it works.

Comment: Also, if I go directly to `https://web.domain.tld:5000/` it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Apache is generating a `Host:` header based on the target server's hostname, whereas I need it to be preserved. Adding `ProxyPreserveHost On` fixes the issue.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40519_01/studio.310/studio_install/src/cidi_studio_reverse_proxy_apache_proxypreservehost.html)